# How do I replace the battery in my Nokia Lumia 920?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, battery

I need to replace the battery in my Nokia Lumia 920.

- How do I replace it?
- What tools are needed?
- What's the name of the new battery?

  - Can I buy the replacement battery directly from Nokia? *I can use Borderlinx if I have to.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The battery in the Lumia 920 is not user-replaceable. If you attempt to open the device and remove the battery, you may damage your phone and will void its warranty. To have the battery replaced, take your phone to an authorised Nokia service centre.

Source: [Nokia Lumia 920 - Battery and charger info](http://www.nokia.com/gb-en/support/product/lumia920/userguidance/?action=singleTopic&topic=S-BATTERY-CHARGER-INFO)

If you want to take the risk of replacing the battery yourself, [a guide to do so is available](http://wmpoweruser.com/guide-on-replacing-your-nokia-lumia-920-battery).

Comment: It may be worth summarizing that guide in your answer, should it fall off the Internet, never to be found again...

Comment: @RowlandShaw I don't think it's worth it. For one, even if that link goes down, it doesn't affect the main point of my answer, which is "don't do this yourself". And secondly, it's a video guide that can't be simply copy&pasted, and I don't want to assume the implied responsibility of having transcribed all the instructions correctly.